# React native navigation with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have an inbox component which fetches all the notifications from the server and lists in a view. The code for which looks like,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'

import {List, ListItem, SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements'
import Header from '../common/Header'
import { Container } from 'native-base'
import PushNotifications from '../../fcm/notifications/PushNotifications'
import NotificationDetails from './NotificationDetails';

export const Navigator = new StackNavigator({
  NotificationList: { screen: NotificationList },
  NotificationDetail: { screen: NotificationDetail },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'NotificationList',
})

class NotificationList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    }
    this.loadNotificationDetails = this.loadNotificationDetails.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const{dispatch,actions} = this.props
    dispatch(actions.getNotification())
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        const{dispatch,actions} = this.props
        dispatch(actions.getNotification())
      }
    )
  }

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        const{dispatch,actions} = this.props
        dispatch(actions.getNotification())
      }
    );
  }
  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />
  }

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    )
  }

  loadNotificationDetails = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationDetails')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container >
        <Header />
        <List containerStyle={{ marginTop: 0, borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.listNotification}

            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.loadNotificationDetails()}>
                <ListItem
                  roundAvatar
                  title={`${item.text}`}
                  subtitle={item.dateTime}
                  // avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
                  containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={50}
          />
        </List>
        <PushNotifications />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default NotificationList;
```

Now what i want to achieve is on clicking any of the listItem, i want to load the complete detailed notification.
Whats happening is when i click it seems to be missing the navigation object. Hence its complaining cannot find property of navigate. 
The props is having only the items from the redux store, i am not able to understand how do i get the navigation props into this component which is already having props from the redux store?
How do i achieve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

`StackNavigator` is a factory function instead of a constructor. Have you try

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  NotificationList: { screen: NotificationList },
  NotificationDetail: { screen: NotificationDetail },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'NotificationList',
})
```

It is a bit confusing, however in v2 the team change the api to `createStackNavigator`.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, haven't i already done that? I want to know how does navigate get its correct props?

Comment: Pay attention to the `new StackNavigator()` vs `StackNavigator()`